# Linq where a record contains 2 matched fields

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I’m working with an existing database with a design I’m not in control of, I’m using EF4, and querying using LINQ. I work in VB.Net but would be quite happy to translate a c# solution.

I would like to pull records from a table where two of the fields match a pair of items from a list.

So i have a list of

```
Public Class RequestInfo
    Public Property INSP_ROUTINE_NM As String
    Public Property FEATURE_ID As String
End Class
```

And I would like to query a table and pull any records where both INSP_ROUTINE_NM and FEATURE_ID match one of the Request Info items.

I can use contains easy enough on either of the fields

```
 Dim Features = (From F In MLDb.TBL_FeatureInfoSet _
      Where (C_Request.Select(Function(x) x.INSP_ROUTINE_NM)).Contains(F.INSP_ROUTINE_NM) Select F.FEATURE_ID, F.FEATURE_RUN_NO, F.INSP_ROUTINE_NM).ToList
```

I could use two contains calls but that would pull any record where both records match somewhere in the list not necessarily any one pair from the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**C#**

```
var Features= (from f in MLDb.TBL_FeatureInfoSet
              let q = C_Request.Select(x=>x.INSP_ROUTINE_NM)
              where q.Contains(f.INSP_ROUTINE_NM) || q.Contains(f.INSP_ROUTINE_NM)
              // where q.Contains(f.INSP_ROUTINE_NM) && q.Contains(f.INSP_ROUTINE_NM)
              select new {f.FEATURE_ID, f.FEATURE_RUN_NO}).ToList();
```

Comment: ur solution is ok. I would also suggest to use .ToUpper() or .ToLower() wherever you are trying to match the strings.